# Create object using values by default

Tags: javascript, constructor

```
function Base(x, y) { this._def=0,0; this.x=x; this.y=y; }
```

I want to create an object of two ways:

- Passing values

  ```
  var b = new Base(2, 3)
  ```

  (This is the typical way)
- Using the values that are in field default '_def'. For that example, 0 should be passed to 'x', and another 0 to 'y'.
  But I would want a generic way to be used and called in another constructors.

Comment: In JavaScript you can only really have one constructor (in the convention, that you have used, that the constructor is the object function itself).

Comment: Then, could be used another constructor to pass the field "_def" and the another constructor?  AddDefault(Base, Base._def)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery in your project, here's how it should be:

```
function Base(options) {
    this._options = $.extend( { x:0, y:0 }, options ) ;
    console.log( [this._options.x, this._options.y] );
}

var b = new Base({x:5, y:1});
```

This will output

```
5,1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for (`this._def=0,0` isn't valid syntax) but you could try something like this:

```
function Base(x, y) { 
   if (this._def != null) {
      this.x = this._def[0];
      this.y = this._def[1];
   } else {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this._def = [0,0];
   }
}
```

Which could then be called with:

```
var obj = { _def = [1, 2] };
obj = Base.call(obj);
```

Now `obj.x` is 1, and `obj.y` is 2.